# Push non-zero length files to an array

Tags: javascript

Say I have some files which I need to gather information about and push that information to an array. If they are of non-zero length they should be loaded, but if they are of zero length they should be ignored. Also I need to have the total number of loaded files as a global variable. This seems like a job for a for loop, but how would I structure it before I know the overall number of "long" files? Could I even access the global for within the for loop? If not a for loop, then what is the "correct" way?

Comment: Will you be doing this in node.js, in the browser, or somewhere else?

Comment: Somewhere else :) http://cycling74.com/

Comment: So you're using javascript as an embedded DSL? What options does the file handler give you for the file as a result? How does it know what the contents are?

Comment: There is a huge "object model" that is accessible through js - http://cycling74.com/docs/max5/refpages/m4l-ref/m4l_live_object_model.html  http://cycling74.com/docs/max5/vignettes/js/jsliveapi.html

Comment: Ahh, see, you didn't link that before. I can't know all the product wikis for all your products.

Comment: Didn't think it was relevant, sorry

Answer (score 1):

If you don't know the total number of files in advance, you should use a `while` loop and break on some other condition:

```
var TOTAL_FILES = 0,
    files = [],
    file;

// assume getNextFile() returns the next file in the list...
while (file = getNextFile()){

  // ...and the File object has a length instance attribute...
  if (file.length > 0){
    TOTAL_FILES++;

    // ...and processFile() works some magic on the file and returns it
    files.push(processFile(file));
  }
}
```

This loop will continue executing until `getNextFile()` returns a falsy value (`false`, `null`, `undefined`, etc.).

Comment: This assumes that each file object has a .length property.

Comment: That's a valid assumption. However... What is file = getnextfile()?

Comment: and shouldn't it be while file.length>0?

Comment: @jcolebrand It assumes a lot more than that :-) This is just a pseudo-code example of a way to iterate over an unknown number of files and process each non-empty file.

Comment: @jamesson If you break apart `while (file = getNextFile())` expression, it's simply assigning the return value of `getNextFile()` (which is a made-up function that would return the next file in the list) to the `file` variable and executing the block if that value is defined. I don't know what you're doing to these files to process them, but `while (file.length > 0)` will loop indefinitely unless you're reducing the length of the file during processing.

Comment: Check out this sample code ... http://cycling74.com/docs/max5/tutorials/max-tut/javascriptchapter03.html ouch that's tough to read, they need at least syntax highlighting

Comment: @jamesson `file;` is part of the previous line, which is part of the previous line, declaring variables. Sounds like now is time for a primer in javascript... http://www.codecademy.com/#!/exercises/0

Comment: I just didn't know you could declare variables that way, apologies

Comment: You can't declare them via `file;` (well you could, but that's kinda my point) so you need to understand basic javascript programming better to begin with. It'll do you well to get your hands dirty. Go take some tutorials and buy Crockford's the good parts and learn about javascript. It's quite a fun language, once you understand it.

Answer (score 1):

Not knowing the specifics, I'm going to assume you are getting the files with ajax. Since strings in javascript are like arrays of characters, you can get the length on the responseText on the ajax event. I hope this helps:

With jQuery Ajax...

```
var loadedFileData = [];
window.totalFiles = 0;
["file1", "file2", "file3"].forEach(function(file) {
 $.get("/path/to/files/"+file, function(data) {
  if (data.length) {
    loadedFileData.push(data);
    totalFiles++;
  }
 });
});
```